# Is it possible to quickly clear flags in Apple Mail 6 ( probably with AppleScript)?

Tags: mail.app

I'm running Apple Mail 6.2 on OS X 10.8.2.

I'm wondering how to clear flags easily, maybe a button exists or a shortcut is possible? Currently I need to press the down arrow in flag button and click "clear flag", which is really inconvenient.

I think **AppleScript** is highly promising, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/346471/apple-mail-flag-message-from-keyboard), copy below script into Apple Script Editor and then run

```
tell application "Mail"
set selectedMessages to (selected messages of front message viewer)
if (count of selectedMessages) is greater than 0 then
    repeat with theMessage in selectedMessages
        set flag index of theMessage to 1
    end repeat
end if
end tell
```

Your selected message will flag with Orange. You can flag message with other color by replacing 1 in the script

Comment: Great. I tested it out and discovered that to clear flag just replace the index with -1. Thanks.